# Important topics in the theory of computation

Tags: theory, computation-theory, computation

During my studies at university I had to learn a lot about the theory of computation. I studied the subject for three terms. I had a hard time and I have to admit that I forgot a lot.

I am wondering whether this is a personal problem, or if we just had to learn a lot of (more or less) useless stuff.

So my question is: *What topics in the field of the theory of computation do you think are most important, which parts are worth learning about, and which topics do you use during your normal work?*

Personally, I am glad that I heard about the [theory of languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_theory) (especially the regular languages => regular expressions - when they can be applied and when not) and about the different [time (and space) complexities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory), in particular the O(n) notations.

But we had to study a lot more, including:

- computability theory

  - halting problem
  - semidecidable problems
- theory of complexity

  - p=np?
- theory of logic

  - propositional calculus
  - predicate logic

It was interesting to hear about these topics, but I am not sure how necessary
it is to study them in depth.

I know this question is subjective and the answers will differ a lot
depending on your day-to-day work and personal experience. But I'd like
to know about topics that might be more interesting than I remember.

Comment: You will begin to forget the things you don't use, then a decade later someone will ask you in an interview about them!

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you will forget the important things sometimes, too - that's why I ask here :) Maybe I get a good book recommendation today ... or something similar

Answer (score 6):

> What topics in the field of the theory of computation do you think are most important

The question is vague. Important to *who*?

> which parts are worth learning about?

All of them are worth learning about. This is a special case of the fact that all human endeavours are inherently worth learning about.

If your question is "which topics provide benefits to me larger than the cost of my time and effort to study them?" then that's a question that only you can answer for yourself. The benefit to me of studying, say, ancient Greek history, has nothing to do with how it affects my ability to get my job done.

> Which topics do you use during your normal work?

I use all the topics you listed -- language theory, asymptotic order analysis, decidability, complexity theory, theorem-proving systems, and so on.

I don't use them in a *formal* sense; I am not sitting at my desk using the Master Theorem to derive order analysis for specific algorithms. I use them in the sense that it is very handy to be able to take a proposed language feature and work out quickly whether implementing it would require the compiler to solve a problem that is linear, polynomial, exponential, NP-hard, or equivalent to the halting problem.

For example, it is pretty easy to work out that overload resolution in C# 3 on nested lambdas is NP-hard, but not equivalent to the halting problem. We therefore know that (1) it is a waste of our time to even try to solve the problem in polynomial time, and (2) at least we know that a solution can be found in some amount of time, and (3) we could come up with simple heuristics to detect the bad scenarios and fail fast if we needed to.

I don't personally use proof systems much, though it is helpful to think about problems as a special case of a theorem prover. There are all kinds of language features that are equivalent to problems you throw at a theorem prover, particularly in the field of type inference and flow analysis. Fortunately none of the features of C# actually *require* implementation of a theorem prover; other languages implemented in this building do have that property, like F#.

Comment: Ok, I see your point: it's not only about using this knowledge intentional, but it is important to have a feeling for the subject. But isn't there some topic where you'd say: that should be tought better? For instance when you get a new member for your team (straight from university) - are you satisfied with their theoretical education (although this differs from person to person of course)

Comment: @tanascius: the subjects I would like to see taught better in schools are the *non-theoretical* subjects. Most of the fresh-out-of-college candidates I see who did not go through a cooperative education program like we had at Waterloo have good theoretical knowledge but are bad at things like reading other people's code, writing code that can be maintained by others, finding bugs in their own code, clearly communicating a design or implementation decision in documentation, and so on. Universities with strong co-op programs expose students to this stuff early.